# Data truncation error when insert blob as data type

Tags: java, mysql, insert, javafx, prepared-statement

Currently I am doing create product. As creating products, you need to insert images. So I came out with an file chooser code using JavaFx. When button is on click, it will call this action event to prompt user to choose image from machine.

```
public void handle(ActionEvent event){
     FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

        //Set extension filter
        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilterJPG = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("JPG files (*.jpg)", "*.JPG");
        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilterPNG = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("PNG files (*.png)", "*.PNG");
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(extFilterJPG, extFilterPNG);

        //Show open file dialog
        File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

        try {
            BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(file);
            Image image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bufferedImage, null);
            myImageView.setImage(image);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CreateProductUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
}
```

It works perfectly and I can simply get and display the image chosen by:

```
 myImageView.setImage(image);
 Image image = panel.getMyImageView().getImage();
```

However, when I try to insert this image into database table, I got an error message. Here is my Insert SQL method:

```
 public boolean create() {
    boolean success = false;
    try {
        DBController db = new DBController();
        String dbQuery;
        db.getConnection();

        dbQuery = "INSERT INTO sm_product(productName,productDescription,productPrice,productQuantity,dateOfCreation,productStatus,productImage) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        PreparedStatement psmnt = db.getConnection().prepareStatement(dbQuery);
        psmnt.setString(1, name);
        psmnt.setString(2, desc);
        psmnt.setDouble(3, price);
        psmnt.setInt(4, quantity);
        psmnt.setString(5, datestr);
        psmnt.setString(6, "Available");

        File imageFile = new File("test.png");
        RenderedImage renderedImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null);
        ImageIO.write(renderedImage, "png", imageFile); //Change extension appropriately
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(imageFile);
        psmnt.setBinaryStream(7, (InputStream) fis, (int) (imageFile.length()));
        int s = psmnt.executeUpdate();

        //check the value of s and initialize success appropriately

        return success;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;

}
```

My data type for image column is Blob. And it returns me an "Data truncation: Data too long for column 'productImage' at row 1" error message. I even tried to change the data type to varchar(100) and it does not work. I wonder why.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the exception show out. You image is too long in compare to image column capacity.

You have productImage is BLOB but why you **even tried to change to varchar(100)** it is so strange.

You must change your image colum data type to BLOB. 
For more information, you can see here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html

Hope this help

Comment: Ya I using blob and there comes the error. And when I changed to longBlob, there's no error. But the program just stuck as in it keeps running without display successful message which by right, it supposed to be there if successfully inserted

Comment: For debugging, you should use the BLOB and then save a smaller image. Or you may change data type to LONGBLOB, the data type length specification can be found here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html

Comment: I wonder is it stored as Blob in database table instead of the exact image location path? Because I've never used this before and it seems quite new to me

Comment: You are actually trying to insert the image to the database not the image location.

Comment: Oh ok so blob value in image column supposed to be correct? But how come the jfxsa-run keep running without display successful message even though the data is inserted into table already?

Comment: Blob is OK. I have not tried JFX yet, it keep running may be the saving operation take some times. For ensuring data have been saved to db, you should open it and check.